# How is this invalid syntax?

Tags: python, class, syntax, definition

I have a python module that consists of many function definitions, all static. Then at the end I added a class definition however, the interpreter presents me with the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                      
  File "~/file.py", line 136                                                                         
    class InvalidPredicateError(Exception):                                                 
        ^                                                                                   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't see a problem with this at all. Is it because I'm trying to define a class in a static module?

Comment: We're going to have to see the module that you made to give a definitive answer. It could be a number of things, really.

Comment: It's most likely indenting, usually. Please post your whole code, and be sure that the indenting shown here matches what you're actually editing.

Comment: Yeah, we don't necessarily need to see the whole file, but at least the preceding function/class or a few lines before the problem line.

Answer (score 11):

You have an error on the line(s) before the class.  For example:

```
$ cat -n pyinvclass.py
     1  def f():
     2    return (1, 2
     3  
     4  class InvalidPredicateError(Exception):
     5    pass
$ python pyinvclass.py
  File "pyinvclass.py", line 4
    class InvalidPredicateError(Exception):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: +1 for reproducing the same error message. But the OP seems to think there was no error until he added the class at the end, and if that's true (I'm skeptical), we're just going to have to wait for more details.